# Create a sprite sheet with animated gifs and still images

Tags: gif, sprite, image-sprite

Ive got a range of UI assets, most of which are `png` but one of them is a loading`gif`.

Im combining all of the `png` files into a spritesheet to use on a website, for this im taking the original assets which i have in illustrator adding them into one artboard and exporting as a `png` but for the loading`gif` which i only have as a `gif` is there a program i can compose my all my assets inc the `gif` then publish all as one large `gif` with the loading icon the only animated one ?

Ive tried in illustrator but to no avail, any ideas ?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea. I'd rather keep the sprite sheet and gif separate... Or turning the gif into png sequence, put that in the sprite sheet and use css or javascript to animate it... Or perhaps consider a svg loading icon.

Comment: Maintaining a sprite sheet of animated GIFs sounds like a real chore. I don't see a benefit to wanting to do this. That said, if you really must have one file, convert the animated GIF into individual PNGs in the sprite sheet then animate that via CSS sprite animations.